# Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'number'. ng build --prod

Tags: javascript, angular

Gostaria de saber o que pode estar acontecendo nesse caso. Toda vez que eu tento rodar o comando `ng build --prod` esse erro aparece dizendo que é no arquivo HTML de um dos componentes na linha 76, segue abaixo a tal linha do erro. Ao qual mesmo removendo para testes não funciona. Outra coisa também quando eu executo o comando `ng build` funciona.

```
<app-campo-control-erro [mostrarErro]="verificaValidTouchedEpi('quantidade')" mensagemErro="Informe a quantidade."></app-campo-control-erro>
```

Segue trecho do método `verificaValidTouchedEpi`

```
verificaValidTouchedEpi(campo: string) {
  return (
    !this.formularioEpi.get(campo).valid &&
    (this.formularioEpi.get(campo).dirty || this.formularioEpi.get(campo).touched)
  );
}
```

Esse método é usado em outros campos do meu form mais o erro está dando apenas nessa linha.

Comment: Mostra o codigo do componente relevante também, irá ajuda a analise

Comment: Anderson, poderia mostrar o código dentro do método `verificaValidTouchedEpi` ?

Comment: Você não pode compar se um boolean  (bool) é maior que o outro ele apenas retorna valores true e false

Comment: Anderson, eu vi seu método, mas não consigo identificar o problema. veja bem, o problema é algo igual ao que o Marcos Brinner comentou acima, em algum lugar você está comparando um Booleano com outro, ou com algum número, por exemplo:

`if(false > 2)` Concorda que isso não faz sentido? Ou `if(false > true)` tente identificar algo assim no seu código. Eu pensei que estivesse nesse método `verificaValidToucheEpi` mas pelo visto não está.

Comment: Richard Willian realmente concordo que não faz sentido, porém verifiquei atentamente todo o meu componente e não existe nada do gênero. As únicas condicionais que envolvem booleanos são apenas if(this.formulario.valid) por exemplo.

Comment: O problema eu acho que e que o form ou alguma propriedade sua esta privada e o html não esta achando. da uma olhada neste link de possíveis problemas de código em produção https://github.com/rangle/angular-2-aot-sandbox